# USB Won’t boot up

Tags: system, usb-installation

I installed Ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386 Via Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.9 on to a USB drive; I’m using a Lenovo laptop 32 bit 2 GB of ram, the installer indicated it installed in to the correct USB drive, all looked good. How do I get it to boot up when I plug it in to the USB port on any computer, surely I don’t need change boot order on every computer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you normally have to tell a computer to boot from a USB. They usually only boot from HD, or maybe CD/DVD.

> Insert the bootable USB flash drive that you just created in your target computer and restart it. Most newer computers can boot from a USB flash drive. If your computer does not automatically do so, you might need to edit the BIOS settings.
>
> Restart your computer, and watch for a message telling you which key to press to enter the BIOS setup. It will usually be one of F1, F2, DEL, ESC or F10. Press this key while your computer is booting to edit your BIOS settings. (On HP Mini Netbooks, they correct key is usually F9.)
>
> Instead of editing BIOS settings, you can chose a boot device from the boot menu. Press the function key to enter the boot menu when your computer is booting. Typically, the boot screen displays which key you need to press. It maybe one of F12, F10. **Note: with some motherboards you have to select 'hard disk/USB-HDD0' to choose the USB flash disk**. It may work like this because the system sees the USB drive 'a mass storage device' as a hard disk drive, and it should be at the top of the boot order list.
>
> So you need to edit the Boot Order. Depending on your computer, and how your USB key was formatted, you should see an entry for "removable drive" or "USB media". Move this to the top of the list to make the computer attempt to boot from the USB device before booting from the hard disk.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Booting_the_Computer_from_USB for more info